# Como usar la misma clase de Conexion en todos los formularios

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vba, visual

tengo una duda que nose si es posible hacer. Tengo esta clase dentro del proyecto.

```
        Public Class dbConexion

Dim conexion As New SqlConnection

Try
            conexion.ConnectionString = "data source = MODEL; initial catalog = MASTER; Integrated Security = True"
            conexion.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
End Class
```

Y despues tengo otros formularios con sqlCommand(consulta, "xxxxx"---> Conexion) pero para poder instanciar la conexion tengo que declararla dentro del formulario. Hay alguna manera de usar en el sqlCommand la conexion que esta declarada en la clase dbConexion? O tengo que abrir la conexion dentro del formulario si o si. Soy nuevo en esto, perdonen si no fui demasiado claro.

Comment: Podrias sacar esa conexion a una clase distinta y todos los metodos para realizar la conexion lo haces en la misma clase y luego solo llamar al metodo necesario, podrias usar el Patron Singleton que seria facil que lo entiendas en la conexion. Trabajo con C#, si puedes traspasar c# a visual basic te dejo una respuesta.

Comment: Desconozco que es el Patron Singleton, la verdad que vengo haciendo cosas muy basicas y sencillas con consultas sql. Pero veo que tengo 4 formularios y en todos tuve que declarar la conexion. Como siempre se busca que el codigo sea lo mas sencillo posible, hacer eso que estoy haciendo no lo veo como algo "sencillo". Si queres pasame eso de C# y veo si le puedo dar forma para Visual.

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo creo una clase de conexion y esa la llamadas en cada metodo y cerras la conexion.
Luego esos metodos los llamas en cada formulario, de esta forma estas sacando la conexion de tus formularios y por parametros estarias pasando los datos que usuarias en el where de alguna consulta que puedas repetir, o nombre de tabla.

```
Public Class Conexion
Private ReadOnly Property SqlConnection As SqlConnection

Public Sub New()
    If SqlConnection Is Nothing Then
        SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "data source = MODEL; initial catalog = MASTER; Integrated Security = True"
        Return
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ConectaraBase()
    SqlConnection.Open()
End Sub

Public Function ConsultarUsuario() As String
    ConectaraBase()
    Dim consulta As String = "select * from tbl_usuario"
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(consulta, SqlConnection)
    Dim sqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim retorno As String = String.Empty

    While sqlDataReader.Read()
        retorno = sqlDataReader.GetString(0)
    End While

    Return retorno
End Function

Public Function ConsultarProvincia() As String
    ConectaraBase()
    Dim consulta As String = "select * from tblProvincia"
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(consulta, SqlConnection)
    Dim sqlDataReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim retorno As String = String.Empty

    While sqlDataReader.Read()
        retorno = sqlDataReader.GetString(0)
    End While

    Return retorno
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Ahh vos haces las funciones en la clase de conexion y despues las pasas al formulario que corresponda. El tema que hay consultas que leo la informacion de un combobox y otras de un textbox, osea tendria que hacer otra funcion para que levante la informacion de esos campos. Pero me va a servir para los casos que tenga que solamente ejecutar un select sin valores de los formularios. Gracias Ramiro

Comment: @GuillermoRubio Te va a servir para todo, claro que si tenes datos locales del formulario no tenes que sacar la logica de ahi mismo. Si te sirvio marcala como aceptada